# adding matlab COM reference in visual studio fails

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to invoke a matlab function from my c# code.
I understand that i need to add a COM reference to mlapp.tlb but apparently my matlab isn't installed correctly so vs 2012 doesn't find the reference in the COM list. 
I tried adding the reference by browsing to mlapp.tlb from the add reference menu but i get the following error:
mlapp.tlc bould not be added. please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
Can someone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *unclean* installation of MATLAB could well be the cause of this issue. It might be fixed by registering MATLAB as a COM server. Have you seen http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101093?